# Do not like quality of graphics when exported by Mathematica 9

Tags: graphics, pdf-format, fractals

I have been using *Mathematica* 9 to generate images of fractals for some time, and I noticed an uncomfortable phenomenon when I export the fractal image into a PDF. The lines get thick so that the details of the fractals get lost to some extent. This did not happen when I was using *Mathematica* 8. Now I have to make my pictures in *Mathematica* 9, save them, and export them in *Mathematica* 8, which is really inconvenient. I was just wondering if anyone would have a solution to this problem.

Here are two pictures of the Sierpinski gasket I have. The first was exported in *Mathematica* 8, the other was exported in 9.

[image: Mathematica 8 Image]
[image: Mathematica 9 Image]

The code for generating the gasket is like this:

```
q1 = {0, 0}; q2 = {-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}; q3 = {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2};
F1[{x_, y_}] := .5 ({x, y} - q1) + q1;
F2[{x_, y_}] := .5 ({x, y} - q2) + q2;
F3[{x_, y_}] := .5 ({x, y} - q3) + q3;

S = {{{{0., 0.}, {-.5, -Sqrt[3]/2.}, {.5, -Sqrt[3]/2.}}}};
For[i = 2, i <= 8, i++,
 old = S[[-1]];
 new = Join[
   Table[F1 /@ s, {s, old}],
   Table[F2 /@ s, {s, old}],
   Table[F3 /@ s, {s, old}]
   ];
 AppendTo[S, new]
 ]

Graphics[
 Join[
  Polygon /@ S[[8]]
  ], ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

I personally use a Windows computer, I have noticed this issue on Macs and Linux as well, but only with Mathematica 9. I am guessing there is some parameter of the default setting to change.

Comment: Please show us the code you used to generate the fractal, so that we can try to replicate and then work the problem.

Comment: Platform? Just did a quick-n-dirty on Windows, 9.x MMA, PDF via export looks fine, no details lost compared to notebook...

Comment: I reopened your question.  What method are you using to save/export the graphic?

Comment: Are you using the default style sheet in Mathematica 9?

Comment: and have you tried using `EdgeForm[]` in the graphics expression?

Comment: Hi, I am using the default style sheet in Mathematica 9, and I export the graphic by right click on the graphic and select "Save Graphic As..." to export it into PDF. I just tried adding `EdgeForm[None]` to the graphics expression and it did not seem to improve the quality.